# Question about Vocabulary: Difference between the usages of broad & wide

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I have these two sentences

> Despite certain broad cultural unity developed over the last century, there was no cultural uniformity.

> Despite the fact that certain wide cultural unity had developed over centuries, there was no cultural uniformity.

In both of these sentences, are both broad and wide conveying different meanings or do they convey the same meaning, or the only essential difference between these two sentences is that of structure.

I tried searching it at [collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/english-usage/what-is-the-difference-between-wide-and-broad), but I didn't get the difference so I am asking here.

P.S: I am new to this forum, so please indicate if the above question is inappropriate for the forum , if so , please guide me to the relevant one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is idiomatic; the second is not.

Although **broad** and **wide** have the same general meaning and are sometimes interchangeable, at others they are not, simply because people don't talk that way.

**Wide** tends to be used more of physical spaces - roads, rivers, pavements, paths and the like. It is used in some set phrases. We talk about **eyes wide open**, never *eyes broad open*.

**Broad** tends to be used more figuratively - in broad terms, broadly speaking, broad outlook, broad views.

Sometimes you can use either - a broad/wide range/choice.

These are not rules, just guidelines. The only way to be sure is from experience of their use.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/broad_1

Comment: So by the logic of the argument you are making ,can I assume that Ist statement is the only correct one since wide is fit for the figurative statement we are trying to make in both statements , if so can we just replace wide with broad in second statement and it will work ?

Comment: Also thanks for the reply, I still can't upvote your answer because of my reputation.

Comment: The second sentence is better English _provided_ that you change _wide_ to _broad_.

Comment: Thanks, Kate Bunting